# VBA FormulaR1C1 formula

Tags: excel, vba

the following throws an error. I tried to escape the strings, but no luck. How do I have to correctly enter the following formula into the field:

```
wrkSheet.Range("I6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(G6=TRUE;H6=TRUE);""Correction Transaction"";IF(AND(G6=TRUE;H6=FALSE);""Execution Correction"";IF(AND(G6=FALSE;H6=TRUE);""Reverse Correction"";""Counter Booking"")))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `FormulaR1C1`  to `Formula`, since you are using "A1" notation (e.g.: `G6`, `H6`)

change "`;`" to "`,`", since ";" is not a valid formula separator in VBA

```
Range("I6").Formula = "=IF(AND(G6=TRUE,H6=TRUE),""Correction Transaction"",IF(AND(G6=TRUE,H6=FALSE),""Execution Correction"",IF(AND(G6=FALSE,H6=TRUE),""Reverse Correction"",""Counter Booking"")))"
```